# Visualforce Page: Group by Company and Consecutive Date Ranges

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller, group-by

I have created a Visualforce Page .pdf to output Candidates and their previous Work Experiences.  On the Work Experience records there is a lookup field for Company as well as fields for Title, Start and End date.
A requirement in the output form is to have the Work Experience grouped by consecutive tenure at a company.
Below is an example Work Experience History where the Candidate was originally at Company 1, left for Company 2 and then came back to Company 1 where they have since had multiple roles.

- Company 1, Title 4, 2020-Present
- Company 1, Title 3, 2018-2020
- Company 2, Title 2, 2016-2018
- Company 1, Title 1, 2014-2018

The Grouping in the output form would be...

- Company 1

  - Title 4, 2020-Present
  - Title 3, 2018-2020
- Company 2

  - Title 2, 2016-2018
- Company 1

  - Title 1, 2014-2018

In my controller I can generate a List of Companies and Work Experiences for those Companies.
I am unable to figure out the best way to have each Company iterate through each of the Work Experience records to find the Consecutive Date ranges

```
List<Company__c> companyList = [
  SELECT Id, Name
  FROM Company__c
  WHERE Id IN (
    SELECT Company__c 
    FROM Work_Experience__c
    WHERE Candidate__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('candidateId')
  )
];

//System.debug('Companies ' + companyList);

List<Work_Experience__c> weList = [
  SELECT 
    Id,
    Date_From__c, 
    Date_To__c,
    Company__c
  FROM Work_Experience__c
  WHERE Candidate__c = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('candidateId')
  ORDER BY 
    Date_From__c DESC,
    Date_From__c DESC
];
```

System.debug('Work Experience ' + weList);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out...
The records are outputting to a .pdf VF Page.  We cannot have the .pdf to go on forever so we want to limit the output to 3 Companies.
I created 3 “Company” lists.
I iterated through the Full Work Experience list and compared the first item’s Company to the item in the loop.
If there is a Match I add the item to the 1st Company List then continue iterating.
If the Companies do not match I stop iterating the first loop and iterate again using the previous end point as the new starting point.

```
String CandidtateId = '0030300000aAA13AAG';

  List<Work_Experience__c> weFullList = [
    SELECT 
      Id,
      DateRange__c,
      Company_Name__c
    FROM Work_Experience__c
    WHERE Candidate__c = :CandidtateId
    ORDER BY 
      Date_To__c DESC,
      Date_From__c DESC
  ];

  System.debug('Original weFullList Size = ' + weFullList.size());

  List<Work_Experience__c> weCompanyList1 = new List<Work_Experience__c>();
  List<Work_Experience__c> weCompanyList2 = new List<Work_Experience__c>();
  List<Work_Experience__c> weCompanyList3 = new List<Work_Experience__c>();

  Integer i;
  for(i = 0; i < weFullList.size(); i++)
    if(weFullList[i].Company_Name__c==weFullList[0].Company_Name__c){
       System.debug('Loop1 Company ' + weFullList[i].Company_Name__c);
      weCompanyList1.add(weFullList.get(i));
    }
    else{
      break;
    }

  Integer j;
  for(j = i; j < weFullList.size(); j++)
    if(weFullList[j].Company_Name__c==weFullList[i].Company_Name__c){
        System.debug('Loop2 Company ' + weFullList[j].Company_Name__c);
      weCompanyList2.add(weFullList.get(j));
    }else{
      break;
    }
  
  Integer k;
  for(k = j; j < weFullList.size(); k++)
    if(weFullList[k].Company_Name__c==weFullList[j].Company_Name__c){
        System.debug('Loop3 Company ' + weFullList[k].Company_Name__c);
      weCompanyList3.add(weFullList.get(k));
    }else{
      break;
    }

System.debug('New weCompanyList1 (' + weCompanyList1.size() + ') = ' + weCompanyList1);     
System.debug('New weCompanyList2 (' + weCompanyList2.size() + ') = ' + weCompanyList2);     
System.debug('New weCompanyList3 (' + weCompanyList3.size() + ') = ' + weCompanyList3);
```